# What do you call a chain of 3d figures connected to each other?

Tags: word-request

[image]

Something like this, but instead of people and 2d figures, 3d figures of any shape. Is there a word for it in the English language?

Comment: With most "what do you call"  questions, I ask that you explain why you think English should have such a word.  This might be because the word exists in your native language.  I also ask that you tell us what you found when you looked up the word in your bilingual dictionary, and why this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: [*Durdle Door beach rescue: **Human chain** 'saved man's life'.*](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-dorset-53880284) There's no reason to use different words for 2d / 3d "chains".

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is no.

You need something like [“paper doll chain”](https://www.google.com/search?q=paper+doll+chain).

I don’t know a word for the 3D version. You would have to invent something like “3D doll chain”, “figurine necklace” or “manakin chain”.